# Knex NodeJS How to select rows with max date for each one

Tags: mysql, node.js, knex.js

I'm working with knex in NodeJS. My problem is I totally don't know how to select all rows when there is max date for each one.

I use that code:

```
 .from('liczniki')
      .join('klienci', 'liczniki.klienci_idcustomers', '=', 'klienci.idcustomers')
      .join('odczyty', 'odczyty.liczniki_idliczniki', '=','liczniki.idliczniki' )
      .select('liczniki.numer_licznika', 'odczyty.wartosc')
      .where('klienci.idcustomers', '=', idkl)


      .then((result) => {
        if (!result)  { 
          console.log(result);
          var er = 500;
          return er;
        }
        var pass = result;
        console.log(pass)
        return pass;
      })
```

};

I i have result :

```
     TextRow { numer_licznika: '1234567', wartosc: 10124 },
      TextRow { numer_licznika: '1234567', wartosc: 320820 },
      TextRow { numer_licznika: '1234567', wartosc: 350430 },
      TextRow { numer_licznika: '1234567', wartosc: 302202 },
      TextRow { numer_licznika: '1212121', wartosc: 220004 },
      TextRow { numer_licznika: '1212121', wartosc: 200202 },
      TextRow { numer_licznika: '1212121', wartosc: 9005090 },
      TextRow { numer_licznika: '1212121', wartosc: 33020 } ]
```

I have to select only them when date is latest. I would like to this look like that:

```
  TextRow { numer_licznika: '1234567', wartosc: 10124 },  
  TextRow { numer_licznika: '1212121', wartosc: 33020 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter rows that you are joining in. I would write it as a subquery. Something like this:

```
 .from('liczniki')
      .join('klienci', 'liczniki.klienci_idcustomers', '=', 'klienci.idcustomers')
      .select(
         'liczniki.numer_licznika', 
          knex('odczyty')
            .where('liczniki_idliczniki', knex.ref('liczniki.idliczniki'))
            .select(knex.raw('max(??)', ['wartosc']))
            .as('wartosc')
      )
      .where('klienci.idcustomers', '=', idkl)
```

https://runkit.com/embed/q4dgylmnp69e